# Null pointer exceptions Debugging

Tags: android, exception, pointers, null

It's a calculator app, when i click foreg. 9, i get null pointer exceptions at the lines with stars. What could be going wrong? I'm just a beginner.

```
nine.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    String con= input.getText().toString();             
                    handlenumber("9",con);   **
                }
private void handlenumber(String number,String com)  **
    {
        number=new String();
        com=new String();

        if(com.equals("0") || com.equals("") || r!=0){

            input.setText(number);  **                            
            r=0;
        }
        else
            {
            input.setText(com.concat(number));                          
            }   
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you showed it seems like `input` is null, make sure you initialize it / assign to it.

Also, you have two parameters passed to `handlenumber`, don't reassign to them use them. e.g. remove the lines:

```
number=new String();
com=new String();
```

Comment: OP Is showing error at `input.setText(number)`.Here `number` can not be null as it passing `"9"` as a value for `number` so no way it will throw `NullPointerException`. It may be due to `number=new String();`

Comment: that's what I'm saying, it can't be number, so it has to be `input`. and there is no problem with `number = new String()`

Comment: Well, technically there IS a problem with calling 'number = new String()'.. but its not causing the crash since you can assign a textview's text = null. He's just wiping out his values. Most certainly 'input' is null in this case

Comment: @dymmeh - that's another issue that I pointed out, but it's clearly doesn't cause NPE.

Comment: Actually, if you look in his previous method he is accessing 'input' as a member variable. He's doing the same here so that variable should not be null at this point (otherwise it would have crashed on the line 'String con= input.getText().toString();' )

Comment: Unless these are in different classes and he just has an empty 'input' variable in the 2nd class.. then my point is wrong.

Comment: I have input initialized in the oncreate method. Input is not null at all `final EditText input= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input)`

Comment: @dymmeh @Binyamin Sharet @Nishant I have input initialized in the oncreate method. Input is not null at all `final EditText input= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input)`

Comment: @Feona - just to be sure - try printing the value of input to the log before the crash line. and the line `final EditText input= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input)` - is it by any chance done before `setContentView` called?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the below line from your code :

```
    number=new String();
    com=new String();

private void handlenumber(String number,String com)  **
{
    if(com.equals("0") || com.equals("") || r!=0){

        input.setText(number);  **                            
        r=0;
    }
    else
        {
        input.setText(com.concat(number));                          
        }   
}
```